Index change based on another column
Consider this column from df:
PersonEntityID
0   324141
1   
2   425544
3   
4   434456

Can I reindex it so that it changes when there is a new value in the column:
PersonEntityID
0   324141
0   
1   425544
1   
2   434456


Do you want to get a unique index for each unique PersonEntityID? or for consecutive ones+NaNs?

Is possible values for index = 2 is e.g. 100? What is expected ouput?

@for each unique PersonEntityID + consecutive nans until there is a new value in PersonEntityID. There are no duplicates in this case (but would be nice for learning purposes to have it bulletproof in case there are).

@Nazar there are actually many ways to interpret this, I added a comparison, it would be great that you clarify which logic is desired ;)

@mozway yeah I actually realised that I wasn't sure myself, but the examples are great, thank you

You can mask the indices matching NaN positions and ffill to keep the previous existing index:
df.index = df.index.to_series().mask(df['PersonEntityID'].isna()).ffill()

Output:
   PersonEntityID
0        324141.0
0             NaN
2        425544.0
2             NaN
4        434456.0

If you want a new value per unique ID:
df.index = pd.factorize(df['PersonEntityID'].ffill())[0]

If you want a unique value only when a new ID is found you can combine np.maximum.accumulate and factorize:
df.index = np.maximum.accumulate(pd.factorize(df['PersonEntityID'])[0])

Output:
   PersonEntityID
0        324141.0
0             NaN
1        425544.0
1             NaN
2        434456.0

Here is a summary of the differences with a modified input:
   PersonEntityID  consecutive  per_unique  per_new_unique
0        324141.0            0           0               0
1             NaN            0           0               0
2        425544.0            2           1               1
3             NaN            2           1               1
4        324141.0            4           0               1


@Nazar you're welcome. That's why it's always important to clearly explain the logic and if possible to craft an example that shows how it should behave in corner cases. It's not always easy though, I realized there could be 3 different interpretations of "there is a new value" only after posting my initial answer.

Use factorize with forward filling missing values:
df.index = pd.factorize(df['PersonEntityID'].ffill())[0]

Or for general solution use:
s = df['PersonEntityID'].ffill()
df.index = pd.factorize(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())[0]

Output with duplicated values:
df['unique'] = pd.factorize(df['PersonEntityID'].ffill())[0]

s = df['PersonEntityID'].ffill()
df['dupl'] = pd.factorize(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())[0]
print (df)
   PersonEntityID  unique  dupl
0        324141.0       0     0
1             NaN       0     0
2        425544.0       1     1
3             NaN       1     1
4        324141.0       0     2


I think this might fail if you have duplicated values in PersonEntityID (unless desired by OP)
